# Consulta MySQL en Eloquent (Laravel 8)

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8

Estimados colegas estoy intentando hace bastante transformar una consulta de SQL en Eloquent sin éxito. Alguien con mas experiencia podría ayudarme en esta cruzada.
Tengo una tabla de **SERVICIOS** en donde necesito recuperar únicamente el último servicio de cada domicilio_id (fecha) y a su vez validar si el mismo tiene mas de 6 meses de lo contrario no debería verse reflejado en el informe. Con la consulta en SQL obtengo la información necesaria por lo que solo necesitaría ayuda para transformarla en Eloquent dadas las relaciones montadas en el proyecto con dicho modelo.

```
SELECT  
    id,domicilio_id,fecha
FROM 
    servicios , (SELECT domicilio_id AS domicilio , MAX(fecha) as fechaMax 
                    FROM servicios
                    GROUP BY 
                        domicilio_id ) AS fechas
WHERE 
        servicios.domicilio_id = fechas.domicilio AND
        servicios.fecha = fechas.fechaMax AND 
        fecha <= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL '6' MONTH)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ya muchas gracias por su ayuda.
Que tenga un buen día
Slds

Comment: quieres pasar esa consulta tal cual a eloquent?

Comment: Recuerda por favor agregar que has intentado al momento así la comunidad sabrá desde donde empezar a ayudar y previenes el posible cierre de tu publicación, recomiendo leas [ask] y veas como proveer un [mcve]

Comment: Correcto la dificultad esta en transformarla a Eloquent. Muchas gracias tendre en cuenta las observaciones.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes lograrlo utilizando `Query Builder`.

Aquí, te recomendaría utilizar `Join`, debes saber que Laravel te provee con un método llamado `joinSub()` para hacer uso de las subqueries al hacer un join.

Por ende, tu primera tarea debería ser, construir la subquery interna que tienes:

```
$latestServices = DB::table('servicios')
                   ->select('domicilio_id as domicilio', DB::raw('MAX(fecha) as fecha_max'))
                   ->groupBy('domicilio_id');
```

Una vez hecho eso, procedes a construir la consulta principal:

```
$services = DB::table('servicios')
        ->joinSub($latestServices, 'fechas', function ($join) {
            $join->on('servicios.domicilio_id', '=', 'fechas.domicilio')
                 ->where('servicios.fecha', 'fechas.fechaMax');
        })->whereRaw('fecha <= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL '?' MONTH)', [6])
        ->get();
```

Puedes modificar la consulta a tu gusto, utilizando directamente los modelos de Eloquent.

Documentación importante:

- [joinSub()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#subquery-joins)
- [whereRaw()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#whereraw-orwhereraw)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y conocimiento! Intentare implementarlo según instrucciones.